# How to use clickhouse WITH FILL function to fill non-order by column with previous value instead of 0?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Im querying time series data using clickhouse and my goal is to return a table of the number of unique IDs present in the dataset at each date. The following query works as it should except when I use the `WITH FILL` operator to fill in missing dates, it fills in new tuples with uniqueIds equal to 0. Instead I need this value to be the value of the previous tuple, as the value should not change between rows if no new unique ids are present.

Here is the query:

```
select date, 
    max(rolling_sum) as UniqueIdsPresent
from (
    select date, 
        count(distinct id) over (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as rolling_sum 
from test
)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date with
```

Here is a toy dataset:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 123x | 2020-03-02 |
| x567 | 2020-03-02 |
| a123 | 2020-03-02 |
| b456 | 2020-03-02 |
| c233 | 2020-03-03 |
| 123x | 2020-04-01 |
| 145I | 2020-04-01 |

Here is what the query presently returns:

| date | uniqueIDs |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-02 | 4 |
| 2020-03-03 | 5 |
| 2020-03-04 | 0 |
| 2020-03-05 | 0 |
| 2020-03-06 | 0 |
| ... | ... |
| 2020-03-31 | 0 |
| 2020-04-01 | 6 |

and this is what I want it to return:

| date | uniqueIDs |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-02 | 4 |
| 2020-03-03 | 5 |
| 2020-03-04 | 5 |
| 2020-03-05 | 5 |
| 2020-03-06 | 5 |
| ... | ... |
| 2020-03-31 | 5 |
| 2020-04-01 | 6 |

As you can see, the number of uniqueIDs shouldn't reset to 0 for tuples with missing dates - it should carry the value from the previous tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using `INTERPOLATE`

```
select date, 
    max(rolling_sum) as UniqueIdsPresent
from (
    select date, 
        count(distinct id) over (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as rolling_sum 
    from test2
)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date 
with FILL INTERPOLATE (UniqueIdsPresent AS UniqueIdsPresent)
```